# Need help adding download feature to MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a web MVC application that I would like to add feature that gives users the ability to download large files from my server. The users have a combination of Mac and Windows PC. I was thinking along the lines of javasripts or silverlight.

Can someone  advice me on how to implement this feature?
Do you have any code examples?

Comment: what kind of files to be downloaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) method of `Controller` class.

So Create a Controller called `FilesController` and have an action method called `DownLoad`

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{  
   public ActionResult Download(string fileId)
   {
     var fullFilePath=FileService.GetFullPath(fileId);  // get the path to file
     return File(fullFilePath,"application/pdf","yourDownLoadName.pdf");  
   }
}
```

This Will return a PDF file from the specified path(**fullFilePath**) with the `MimeType/ContentTyp`e as **PDF** and "**yourDownLoadName.pdf**" as the Downloadable file name

Users can access this like `http://yourdomainname.com/Files/Download?fileId=somefileId`

This method has got a bunch of [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) using file path, byte array ,stream etc..

Comment: This is quick and simple and nice. Thanks. However I would add a a progress bar...and these files are like 1GB not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: @user1204195 - you should possibly consider editing your question to reflect the fact that you really want a way to download massive files with a progress bar.

Comment: I do not encourage to edit the question once people answered for that. The OP should have included the relevant details in the first time.

Comment: I am actually downloading an .mp4 file. I can open/play the file but nothing happens when I save it . Here is my code:   public ActionResult Download(string fileId)
            {
                //var fullFilePath = FileService.GetFullPath(fileId);  // get the path to file
                var fullFilePath = fileId;
                return File(fullFilePath, "application/octet-stream", "yourDownLoadName.mp4");
            }

Comment: @user1204195 I encourage you to post it as a new question with relevant details and code. so that it will hit a large audience and you will get the specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller action with a [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx) return type.